# How to delete from Table1 and rows associated in Table2

Tags: c#, sql-server

Table1: `StudentID, StudentName`
Table2: `DetailsID, StudentID, Gender, Age`

I want to delete a record from `Table1` so that it will delete all records from `table2`.

Many thanks

Comment: What technology are you using for your data layer. I would also suggest adding StudentID to table 2 as your foreign key.

Comment: What if two students have same name? You should use Student ID which is unique to identify the user to be deleted.

Comment: Use referential integrity with cascade delete.

Comment: I used this: SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("delete from Table1 where StudentName in (select StudentName from Table2 where Table1.StudentName= Table2.StudentName", con); but not working!

Comment: Wow you alter your question all the time, so that i have to update my answer... Did you try it with the foreign key?

Comment: Yes, it's foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need following SQL code?

```
delete from table1
where exists (
    select * from table2 where table2.StudentName = Table1.StudentName
)
```

Comment: That would delete every entry from Table1 with a corresponding item in Table2. SO maybe it would delete everything in Table1 and nothing in Table2 or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: I use this: SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("delete from table1 where exists (select * from table2.StudentName = table1.StudentName)", con); but it's error: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @mhshojaee: You should write it like this: Select * from Table2 t2 join Table1 t1 on t2.StudentName = t1.StudentName

Answer (score 2):

You should alter your Table2 to delete on cascade with a foreign Key Contraint and you should not using the student name there as Shoban, Hamlet Hakobyan and Peter Smith statet before.

```
ALTER TABLE Table2   WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2_Table1] FOREIGN KEY([StudentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([StudentID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Then when you delete a Student in Table1 the rows with the same StudentId in Table2 will get deleted automatically.

In Table2 youd don#t need the StudentName, if the StudentId there is filled properly you can drop the column StudentName in Table2 because it exists already in Table1.

```
ALTER Table Table1 drop column StudentName
```